# How do you escape a formatted element in a contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I have a `contenteditable` div. I'm trying to figure out how to escape formatted elements like `<sup></sup>`, `<code></code>` etc. on `keydown` event:

### Code

```html
<div 
  id="editor" 
  contenteditable="true" 
  @input="editorInputHandler"
  @keydown="editorKeydownHandler"
></div>
```

Data:

```html
<p>test<sup>2{CURSOR_POSITION}</sup></p>
```

Handler:

```js
function editorKeydownHandler (event) {
  const selection = window.getSelection()
  const selectionTag = selection.anchorNode.parentNode.tagName
  const selectionElementNode = selection.anchorNode
  if (event.code === 'Enter' && selectionTag === 'SUP') {
    // Creating a temp target for the cursor ?
    // let span = document.createElement('span')
    // selectionElementNode.parentNode.appendChild(span)
    // ...
  }
}
```

### Question

How do you move the cursor out of a formatted element (to the end of the parent tag) on `enter` keydown, like this:

```html
<p>test<sup>2{MOVE_CURSOR_FROM_HERE}</sup>{MOVE_CURSOR_TO_HERE}</p>
```

Currently it just keeps dragging the formatting when you hit `enter`:

```html
<p>test<sup>2</sup></p><p><sup><br>{TYPING_WILL_CONTINUE_FROM_HERE}</sup></p>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, as content is wrapped and cursor is inside <sup>, would have been possible if there was content after <sup> I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the place of the selection to the end of the parent element by setting the offset to the length of the parent. Assume sup is your superscript element.

```
let selection = window.getSelection();
selection.collapse(sup.parentNode, sup.parentNode.childNodes.length);
```

Then do the same for focusNode to ensure no text is selected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work. The `.anchorNode` and `.anchorOffset` are `read only` properties and cannot be set

Comment: Sorry, you have to use the `collapse()` method to change the selection. My mistake

Answer (score 0):

Found a solutions for this. If someone knows a better one, please let me know.

```js
...
if (event.code === 'Enter' && selectionTag === 'SUP') {
  event.preventDefault()
  // Insert a 'space' symbol at the end
  selection.anchorNode.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '&nbsp;')
  // Select the parent node
  selection.selectAllChildren(selection.anchorNode.parentNode)
  // Collapse selection to the end, effectively moving the cursor out of the formatted element
  selection.collapseToEnd()
}
```